# Linux mint 17 no sound at all

Tags: audio, linux-device-driver, linux-mint

I'm new to linux mint, I have been working on it for a week now and the sound is not working at all. I tried a lot of the solutions suggested online but no luck. 
Can anyone guide me where the problem might be or how to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if you have the right audio device enabled in the Sound Settings menu?